# HTLM5 Canvas: remove gaps between rotated sprites

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

So I'm making a little tile-based spaceship game and I ran into a problem where when the tile sprites are rotated as the ship rotates, there appear to be small gaps between the tiles. I looked into this and discovered that anti-aliasing might have something to do with it, but after using `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled= false;` I still see no change.

Here it looks as it should, when everything is at a 90 degree angle, it looks fine:

[The spaceship with no gaps between sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm1Ai.png)

[Another example with a ship looking fine at a 90 degree angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dsEU.png)

However, when the ship is rotated:

[Gaps between the sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W37w.png)

Here is an example of the 'grid' used to visualize the borders of tiles:

[Tile grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57cKP.png)

Currently, I am using a system that 'splits up' larger 2x2 tile sprites into 4 1x1 tiles. I could change it to render the whole 2x2 tile and mostly get around this problem because it would be much less obvious, but I am wondering if there is a solution where there will be no gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply render it once on an off-screen canvas, and rotate this complete image, instead of composing it every time.

```js
// the main context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// an off-screen canvas
const ship = document.createElement('canvas');
const ship_renderer = ship.getContext('2d');
ship.height = ship.width = 150; 
const sprites = new Image();
sprites.onload = begin;
sprites.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/scISJ.png';
let angle = 0;


function begin() {
  drawShip(ship_renderer); // render once complete
  anim(); // rotate
}

// draw our sprites on given context
function drawShip(renderer) {
  for(let y=0; y<6; y++) {
    for(let x=0; x<6; x++) {
      renderer.drawImage(sprites,
        (x + y * 6) * 25, 0, 25, 25,
        x * 25, y * 25, 25, 25
      );
    }
  }
}

function anim() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  angle += Math.PI / 180;
  
  // draw our complete image on the left
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,75,75);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(-75, -75);
  ctx.drawImage(ship, 0, 0);

  // draw like OP on the right
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,225,75);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(-75, -75);
  drawShip(ctx);
  
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```css
canvas{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out when I have time next weekend